# javascript and css files are not visible in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I've got such folder structure.

[image]

My default scripts are not visible so I decided to create simple javascript file `test.js` with simple function `func`.

```
function func() {
    alert('hello world!');
}
```

My `jsp` page looks like this.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>PrettyXML</title>
    <!-- <script src="/resources/page/vkbeautify.js"></script>
    <script src="/prettify.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/prettify.css"/>-->
    <script src="/resources/page/test.js"></script>
    <script>
        var pr_amp = /&/g;
        var pr_lt = /</g;
        var pr_gt = />/g;
        var pr_quot = /\"/g;

        function textToHtml(str) {
            /*return str.replace(pr_amp, '&amp;')
            .replace(pr_lt, '&lt;')
            .replace(pr_gt, '&gt;');*/
        };

       function updateText() {
            /*var text = textToHtml(vkbeautify.xml('${data}'));
            document.getElementById('xml').innerHTML=text;*/
            func();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="updateText(), prettyPrint()" bgcolor="white">
    <pre id="xml" class="prettyprint"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

But it still says that `func is not defined`. Where to locate javascript and css files?

Comment: Is the file available or does it throw 404 not found status code? Why do you specify ISO encoding in JSP but UTF-8 in HTML ?

Comment: the page is loaded fine. Javascripts and css are not visible.

Comment: I mean, the JS file, is it getting loaded? Please confirm by adding a screenshot of the console and the 200 ok status.

Comment: `<script src="resources/page/test.js"></script>`

Comment: Oh I see. It's not found. 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

If youre 100% sure the file is getting loaded properly, the error is in here:

```
onload="updateText(), prettyPrint()"
```

You have `,` instead of `;`:

```
onload="updateText(); prettyPrint();"
```

Besides that, you should only specify **one** encoding, not both ISO **and** UTF-8.

Comment: Well it seems it cannot find this javascript file. It tries to load it from `http://localhost:8080/prettify.js`

Comment: @user1432980 you commented out the prettify.js line, how should it try to load it? Btw multi-line comments must be end with `//-->`, single line comments with `-->`.

Comment: It's the same for `test.js`. It only add `8080/resources/page/test.js`. I simply uncommented lines